# jQuery inverted selector given a list of values

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to be able to remove elements based on a list.  This has to be easy to do but I'm not seeing the forest through the trees here.

I want to pass in multiple values in a single list.   Remove elements not in the list.

```
    <select id="productList">
    <option value="CD-6">6 Month CD 10K</option>
    <option value="CD-12">12 Month CD 10K</option>
    <option value="CD-24" selected="selected">24 Month CD 10K</option>
</select>
```

That is a static list.  I want to leave lets say "CD-12, CD-24" and remove CD-6.

```
$("#productList option:not:contains('CD-12, CD-24')").remove();
```

Not working, anyone got an idea?

Comment: `$("#productList option:not(:contains('CD-12, CD-24'))").remove();`?

Comment: #productList option:not([value='CD-12'],[value='CD-24']) works properly

Comment: yep that should work. I don't think `:contains` checks values, which was an oversight on my part the first time through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#productList option:not([value='CD-12'],[value='CD-24'])");
```

This works properly and gives the desired output.  Only CD-12 and CD-24 remain in the listbox.

Comment: That is not valid CSS3 Selector syntax.  The :not pseudo selector only accepts 1 simple selector.  What I posted is correct.  This must be fault with jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

Using contains() is not a good idea, you should be testing the value attribute.

```
$("#productList option:not([value='CD-12']):not([value='CD-24'])").remove()
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.  I'll have to do some string concatenation but otherwise this should work perfect.  Thank you!

Comment: This doesnt seem to be working quite right unless im missing something.  The first CD-12 remains, but the SECOND is removed.  I need both to remain.  How do we make the NOT's OR operators?

Comment: FWIW $("#productList option:not([value='CD-12'][value='CD-24'])"); did not work either